# Example of subdirectly irreducible algebra that contains a proper sub-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

I read that an algebra $\textbf{A}$ is subdirectly irreducible if whenever $\textbf{A}$ is isomorphic to a sub-algebra of a direct product $\Pi_{i \in I}\textbf{C}_i$, it has to be the case that $\textbf{A}$ is isomorphic to $\textbf{C}_j$ for some $j \in I$.

I would like to ask, is it possible for there to be a subdirectly irreducible algebra that contains proper sub-algebras ? Is there any example in the case of groups ?

Comment: Every non-trivial group has a proper (trivial) subgroup and every simple group is subdirectly irreducible. Are you sure this is the question you meant to ask?

Comment: You cannot conclude that $A$ is isomorphic to some $C_j$: you can only conclude that $A$ is isomorphic to a subalgebra of a $C_j$.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a totally clear definition but I think your definition is incorrect: I think it's that whenever $A \to \prod_i A_i$ is a subdirect representation (meaning that the projection to each $A_i$ is surjective; you omit this condition) then there is some $i$ such that the projection to $A_i$ is an isomorphism (you omit the condition that the isomorphism is induced by a projection).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of subdirectly irreducible is  not quite right: the correct conclusion is that $\mathbf{A}$ is isomorphic to a subalgebra of $\mathbf{C}_j$ for some $j\in I$, and that the isomorphism is induced by the embedding into the direct product.

In fact, the usual definition is the following (e.g., Jacobson's *Basic Algebra II*):

> **Definition.** An $\Omega$-algebra $\mathbf{A}$ is subdirectly irreducible if and only if the intersection of all nontrivial congruences of $\mathbf{A}$ is nontrivial.

For instance, in the case of groups this would become:

**Definition.** A group $G$ is subdirectly irreducible if and only if it contains a minimum nontrivial normal subgroup $N$ (i.e., a subgroup $N$ such that $N\triangleleft G$ and if $K\triangleleft G$, then either $K=\{e\}$ or $N\leq K$).

And for rings,

**Definition.** A ring $R$ is subdirectly irreducible if and only if it contains a a minimum nontrivial ideal.

And for modules,

**Definition.** An $R$-module $M$ is subdirectly irreducible if and only if the intersection of all nontrivial submodules of $M$ is nontrivial.

In the case of groups, for instance, we would have:

**Theorem.** A group $G$ is subdirectly irreducible if and only if for every $f\colon G\to \prod_{i\in I}G_i$, if $f$ is one-to-one then there exists $j\in I$ such that $\pi_j\circ f\colon G\to C_j$ is one-to-one. In particular, $G$ is isomorphic to a subalgebra of $C_j$.

*Proof.* Assume first that $G$ has a minimal nontrivial normal subgroup $N$, and that $f\colon G\hookrightarrow \prod_{i\in I}G_i$ is an embedding into a direct product. Consider the maps $\pi_i\circ f\colon G\to G_i$. The kernel of $\pi_i\circ f$ is either trivial or contains $N$. Since $f$ is one-to-one, the intersection of all kernels must be trivial. Thus, at least one kernel $\mathrm{ker}(\pi_j\circ f)$ does not contain $N$, which means that it is trivial. Hence, $\pi_j\circ f$ is an embedding and $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G_j$.

Conversely, the family of maps $\pi_K\colon G\to G/K$ as $K$ ranges over all nontrivial normal subgroups of $G$ induces a morphism $f\colon G\to \prod_{\{e\}\neq K\triangleleft G} G/K$. The kernel of this map is the intersection of all nontrivial normal subgroups of $G$. Since none of the maps $\pi_K\colon G\to G/K$ are embeddings, the morphism $f$ is not an embedding, hence the intersection of all nontrivial normal subgroups of $G$ is nontrivial, proving that $G$ has a minimum nontrivial normal subgroup, as claimed. $\Box$

**Examples.**

1. The groups $\mathbf{C}_{p^n}$, $p$ a prime, $n\geq 1$, are subdirectly irreducible. When $n\gt 1$, they all have proper nontrivial subgroups.
2. The Prüfer $p$-group $\mathbf{C}_{p^{\infty}}$ is subdirectly irreducible.
3. The groups $S_n$, $n\geq 2$, are subdirectly irreducible. For $n\neq 4$, the minimum normal subgroup is $A_n$; for $n=4$ it is the Klein $4$-subgroup $\{e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$.
4. Fields are subdirectly irreducible; any non-prime field contains a proper subfield.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you meant that the isomorphism is induced by some embedding of $C_j$ into the direct product (which exists for e.g. groups but not rings). You meant that the isomorphism is induced by the composite of the embedding of $A$ into $\prod C_i$ and the projection to $C_j$, right?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Yes, exactly. (Embeddings into the product exist in the category of Rings-not-necessarily-with-unity, but not for rings with unity, of course....)

Comment: Great, thanks. For some reason Wikipedia does not include a formal definition of subdirectly irreducible (only an informal one) and the first pdf I found when I went looking for a definition omitted a quantifier.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: The standard definition is in terms of congruences, rather than embeddings into a direct product; you can turn that definition into one about embedding into a direct product using the process above.